# Correct way to pass NSError from URLSession

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsurlsession, objective-c-2.0

I have Network layer class, which has method with URL request. Seems like this:

```
- (void)networkRequestWithError:(NSError *__strong *)responseError
                  andCompletion:(void (^)(NSData*))completion
{
    NSURL *url = ...
                        
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [NSURLSession.sharedSession
                                      dataTaskWithURL:url
                                      completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                          NSURLResponse *response,
                                                          NSError *error) {
        // *responseError = error; for real errors
        *responseError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"1"
                                             code:1
                                         userInfo:@{}];        
        completion(data);
    }];
    
    [dataTask resume];
}
@end
```

I create instance of this network layer in controller and I want to handle error in completion block:

```
    __block NSError *responseError; 
    
    [self.networkService networkRequestWithError:&responseError
                                  withCompletion:^(NSData*) {
                
        if (responseError != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@",responseError.localizedDescription);
        } else {
            //Some action with data. No matter
        }
    }];
```

**Problem:** responseError has some value in dataTask completion scope (when I init it), but in my completion block in controller it always nil. I don't have any idea why.

Comment: Why do you want to manage it this way when you have the completion handler? Why not put it as as a var of the block?

Comment: I’m trying to use Obj-C style. I know that in Obj-C uses NSError instance link as method argument to handle any errors. Usually I’m writing on Swift, and your solution is good and seems like Result<Success,Error> in completion closures. But is this a correct way to error handling in Obj-C? Handling errors from URLSessionDataTask should be a trivial issue, and should has some best practice, I hope. This is a reason why I go to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Best practice? For async error, use the solution as mattt, use the handler. For sync error, yes use an NsError param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an asynchronous method. Don’t set the response error by indirection. Do exactly what `dataTaskWithURL` does: pass it as another parameter into the completion block.

```
 - (void)networkRequestWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSData*, NSError*))completion
```

Comment: OK, thank you for the answer. Can you help me with understanding? Yes, it’s asynchronous method, but I’m passing error instance by the link and set value only before calling completion block. I don’t understand why error is nil in completion.

Comment: In a comment, you asked: "But is this a correct way to error handling in Obj-C?" Yes. As I said in my answer, the way `dataTaskWithURL` works proves it. It doesn't provide an error by indirection; it hands the error down into its completion handler. Go Ye And Do Likewise.

Answer (score 0):

For a technical explanation of why your code didn't work, it has to with the fact that `__block` variables can be moved, and thus getting a pointer to it at one point doesn't mean that the pointer still points to the variable later. You have to be careful when taking the address of a `__block` variable.

As an optimization, blocks start out on the stack, and `__block` variable also start out in a special structure on the stack. When some code need to store the block for use after the current scope, it copies the block, which causes the block to be moved to the heap if it isn't already there (since things on the stack may not live beyond the current call). Moving a block to the heap also causes any `__block` variables that the block captures to be moved to the heap if it isn't already there (again, since it needs to be on the heap to outlive the current call).

Normally, when you get or set a `__block` variable, the compiler translates that into several pointer lookups behind the scenes to access the real location of the `__block` variable, so it transparently works, no matter if it's on the stack or heap. However, if you take the address of it to get a pointer, as in `&responseError`, you only get the address of it as the variable currently is, but it does not get updated if the variable is moved.

So what is happening in your case is that the `__block` variable `responseError` in your second piece of code starts out on the stack, and when you do `&responseError`, you get a pointer to its location on the stack. This pointer is passed into `-networkRequestWithError:withCompletion:`, and this pointer (confusingly also called `responseError`) is then captured into the block it creates and passes into `-[NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:]`.

At the same time, the `__block` variable `responseError` in your second piece of code is captured by the block you pass into `-networkRequestWithError:withCompletion:`, and this block (called `completion`) is then captured by the block you pass into `-[NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:]`. That is an asynchronous operation, so they copy the block, which copies the first block, which moves the blocks, as well as the `__block` variable `responseError`, to the heap.

By the time the completion handler of `-[NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:]` is called asynchronously, the stack frame where the original `__block` variable `responseError` was created has ended, and the pointer that we captured (called `responseError` in `-networkRequestWithError:withCompletion:`, which is a pointer to the original `__block` variable `responseError` on the stack) is a dangling pointer. Assigning to the thing pointed to by that pointer is undefined behavior, and may actually be overwriting some unrelated variables on the stack. On the other hand, the actual `__block` variable `responseError` on the heap is not changed, and still holds the value it originally held (`nil`).

In your second piece of code, if you printed out the address of `responseError` (`&responseError`) before the block and within the block, you will see that they are different, demonstrating that it was moved.